# Отправка protobuf полей в python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-protobuf

Что бы получить ответ от сайта мне необходимо отправить protobuf сообщение в Post запросе, отследил запрос с помощью Charlie, и там все в таком виде:[image: Данные которые необходимо отправить]

Как мне отправить подобное сообщение python средствами?